# Convert multiple lines of string into a JSON based on a delimiter

Tags: python, json, recursion

I am literally lost with ideas on converting multiple lines of string into a JSON tree structure

So, I have multiple lines of string like below under a particular excel column:

```
/abc/a[2]/a/x[1]
/abc/a[2]/a/x[2]
```

Since the above strings contain the delimiter `/` , I could use them to create a parent-child relationship and convert them into a Python dictionary (or) JSON like below:

```
{
  "tag": "abc",
  "child": [
    {
      "tag": "a[2]",
      "child": [
        {
          "tag": "a",
          "child": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "child": [
                {
                  "tag": "x[1]"
                },
                {
                  "tag": "x[2]"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am unable to come up with a logic for this part of my project since I need to look for the presence of [1],[2] and assign them to a common parent and this needs to be done in some recursive way that works for strings with any length. Please help me out with any code logic in Python or provide me with suggestions. Much appreciated !!

**Additional Update:**
Just wondering if it would also be possible to include other column's data along with the JSON structure.

For ex: If the excel contains the below three columns with 2 rows

| tag | text | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /abc/a[2]/a/x[1] | Hello | string |
| /abc/a[2]/a/x[2] | World | string |

Along with the JSON from the original question, is it possible to add these other column information as key-value attributes (to the corresponding innermost child nesting) in the JSON like below.
These do not follow the same '/' delimiter format, hence I am unsure on approaching this..

```
{
  "tag": "abc",
  "child": [
    {
      "tag": "a[2]",
      "child": [
        {
          "tag": "a",
          "child": [
            {
              "tag": "a",
              "child": [
                {
                  "tag": "x[1]",
                  "text": "Hello",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "tag": "x[2]",
                  "text": "World",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

P.S: I felt it would be appropriate to add the data to the innermost child to avoid information redundancy... Please feel free to suggest including these other column in any other appropriate way as well.

Comment: Did the function to_dict in my answer fit you or you would like somehow different function?

Comment: Yes, your code works fine.. I just had to connect it to my excel column, loop over every row and create the JSON out of it. Additionally, included other columns as key-value pairs. I was just facing trouble with the JSON and both the solution works like a charm. Thanks again, mate

Comment: What is delimiter between columns? Post new example data as string like you did with 1. example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections, json
def to_tree(d):
   v = collections.defaultdict(list)
   for [a, *b], *c in d:
      v[a].append([b, *c])
   return [{'tag':a, **({'child':to_tree(b)} if all(j for j, *_ in b) else dict(zip(['text', 'type'], b[0][-2:])))} 
            for a, b in v.items()]

col_data = [['/abc/a[2]/a/x[1]', 'Hello', 'string'], ['/abc/a[2]/a/x[2]', 'World', 'string']] #read in from your excel file
result = to_tree([[[*filter(None, a.split('/'))], b, c] for a, b, c in col_data])
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "tag": "abc",
        "child": [
            {
                "tag": "a[2]",
                "child": [
                    {
                        "tag": "a",
                        "child": [
                            {
                                "tag": "x[1]",
                                "text": "Hello",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "tag": "x[2]",
                                "text": "World",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Clean and elegant. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot mate !!

Comment: If I need to add other column values from my excel row to the JSON's corresponding  innermost child, any suggestions on where I could add them?

Comment: @Parsh Can you post a sample of the new column data and how the final result should look? If your second column values follow the same path structure as your first column, than you can just combine both columns as a single list and pass to `to_tree`, but I am not quite sure if that is in fact how your second column values are structured.

Comment: Unfortunately, they do not follow the same delimiter '/' format. I have included a sample example in the question. Kindly do help if possible... In case, adding these other column's data is not possible along with the innermost child, you may also suggest any other viable JSON structure that displays the data in a meaningful way..

Comment: This is simply perfect. Made my day. Thanks @Ajax1234 !!

Comment: @Parsh Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
def to_dict(data, old_data=None):
    json={}
    if old_data!=None:
        json["child"]=old_data
    for row in data.split("\n"):
        path=json
        for element in row.strip("/").split("/"):
            if not "child" in path:
                path["child"]=[]
            path=path["child"]
            for path_el in path:
                if element==path_el["tag"]:
                    path=path_el
                    break
            else:
                path.append({"tag":element})
                path=path[-1]
    return json["child"]
#tests:
column="""/abc/a[2]/a/x[1]
/abc/a[2]/a/x[2]"""
print(to_dict_2(column))
print(to_dict_2(column,[{'tag': 'abc', 'child': [{'tag': 'old entry'}]}]))
```

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate your time. Works as expected !

Comment: Curious question: In my excel, if column 1 contains the values(rows) I pass as the 'data' variable and I want to append the excel's corresponding column 2's value along with each innermost child (along with the child that contains tag after the last '/') in the JSON. Is that possible directly or would I be required to tweak the code a bit ?

Comment: @Parsh, I did not understand your question.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example under the "Additional Update" heading.

Comment: @Parsh, in what format is this data given to program? If as string, then what symbol is between columns?

Comment: The table in the example is a CSV file, which I have read into a Pandas Dataframe. And for example, to use it into Ajax's solution, I had converted them as a list of lists using `df.values.tolist()`

Comment: If a child is added to an element, that already had keys "text" and "type" - should these keys be removed then?

Comment: If element is added to dictionary on location, where already was element with same tag, should the keys be then updated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ndjson](https://pypi.org/project/ndjson) package (with which I am not associated, but am a with-some-success user). To install,

```bash
pip install ndjson
```

In their example,

```py
import ndjson

# load from file-like objects
with open('data.ndjson') as f:
    data = ndjson.load(f)

# convert to and from objects
text = ndjson.dumps(data)
data = ndjson.loads(text)

# dump to ndjson file-like object
with open('backup.ndjson', 'w') as f:
    ndjson.dump(data, f)
```

So it's fine for you to just follow this with:

```py
import json

# dump to json file-like object
with open('backup.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Hope that helps!